How to calculate lateral deviation of a vehicle from a linear path
I am looking to find equations to allow me to calculate the lateral deviation of a vehicle from its desired path when there is an unexpected input to the steering.
The scenario is that the vehicle is travelling on a straight road within a defined lane.  The is an unexpected shock input to the steering that causes the wheels to turn slightly.  There is a reaction time for the driver to respond, counter steering to bring the vehicle back to the original path in the centre of the lane.  The key figure to find is the peak lateral movement within the lane.  I.e. does it actually depart from the lane.
The vehicle has a wheel base of 2.3m and a track width of 1.5 between tyre centres.  The initial shock to the steering results in a change of wheel angle (For simplification I have assumed the same change of angle for both wheels, although of course one will change more than the other. The reaction of the driver is such that the peak wheel angle is seen after 350 ms and is 0.55 degrees.  Again for simplification I have assumed the average as being 0.4125 (75% of the peak).  It then takes the driver 200ms to return the steering to dead centre.  And a further 150ms to get to -0.55 degrees.
I need to calculate how much it moves laterally at different speeds.  The change in steering angle due to the shock and driver reaction times are constant, it is just the vehicle speed which varies.
Can anyone help me with what equations I need to use? If there is any other pertinent data I'd need to gather?

As further information:  I believe I first need to calculate the turning circle.  for this I believe a simplified equation is RadT = WheelBase_m/(sin(WheelAngle)).   The change in actual vehicle direction is VehAngle = 360 * (RadT/x)  where x = v *t.  Then the movement away from the centre line  y =  (x * sin(VehAngle)).
